# Docker for Windows: "Operation not permitted" trying to run an executable inside a container (bind-mount only)

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I'm pretty sure that the last update of Docker for Windows has broken something.

Here is the thing. I have a custom image named `toolbox`, built from alpine, with a bounch of script inside it (bind-mount the local folder `./mnt/`):

```
version: '3'

services:
    # ...

    toolbox:
        build:
            context: ./.docker/toolbox
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - ./mnt/etc/periodic/daily:/etc/periodic/daily
```

Files have the right permissions:

```
/ # ls -la /etc/periodic/daily/
total 4
drwxrwxrwx    1 root     root          4096 Mar 16 17:49 .
drwxr-xr-x    7 root     root          4096 Jan 16 22:52 ..
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           332 Mar  1 23:57 backup-databases
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root            61 Mar  1 23:51 cleanup-databases-backups
```

When I try to execute `backup-databases` I get the following error:

> / # /etc/periodic/daily/backup-databases /bin/sh:
>   /etc/periodic/daily/backup-databases: Operation not permitted

**The strange thing is, if I create a script (from inside the container) it works**:

```
echo "echo Hello" > /etc/periodic/daily/test
chmod +x /etc/periodic/daily/test
/etc/periodic/daily/test
```